# Python startup script using STDOUT for outputs, using init.d method

Tags: python, linux, bash, daemon, startup

My environment is Debian Jesse on a embedded arm display.

I am using a bash script to automatically launch my app using the init.d method. It launches a second python script as a daemon that handles my application on startup and reboot.

Because it is run this way to the best of my knowledge this is now a daemon background process, and it disconnects STDOUT and STDIN from my python script.

The system and application is for a single purpose, so spamming the console with outputs from a background process is not only not a problem, but it is desired. With the outputs I can easily ssh or serial console into the display and see all the live debug outputs or exceptions.

I have looked into possible ways to force the process to the foreground, or redirect the outputs to STDOUT but have not found any definite answer when the script is run at startup.

My logging to a file is working perfect and otherwise the app works well in the state it is in. Currently when I need to debug I stop the application and run it manually to get all the outputs.

I have considered using sockets to redirect the outputs from the app, and then running a separate script that is listening will print to console... but that seems less than ideal and that a better solution might exist.

Is there methods to achieve this or should I just accept this.

**EDIT 1 (additional details)**

Because I am using multiple logs for multiple processes I have created a logger class. The stream handler uses the default which should be sys.stderr.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

class LoggerSetup(object):

    def __init__(self, logName, logFileNameAndPath, logSizeBytes, logFileCount):

        log = logging.getLogger(logName)
        log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - ' + logName + ' - %(message)s',datefmt="%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        # Add the log message handler to the logger

        if(logFileCount > 0):

            fileHandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(logFileNameAndPath, maxBytes=logSizeBytes, backupCount=logFileCount)
            log.addHandler(fileHandler)
            fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

        consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
        log.addHandler(consoleHandler)
        consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

        log.info(logName + ' initialized')
```

For more reference here is the startup script launch on boot. It then runs my python run.py which handles the rest of the startup process.

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          ArcimotoStart
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Startup script
# Description:       startip script that points to run.py
### END INIT INFO

# Change the next 3 lines to suit where you install your script and what you want to call it
DAEMON=/app/run.py
DAEMON_NAME=app

# Add any command line options for your daemon here
DAEMON_OPTS=""

# This next line determines what user the script runs as.
# Root generally not recommended but necessary if you are using certain features in Python.
DAEMON_USER=root

# The process ID of the script when it runs is stored here:
PIDFILE=/var/run/$DAEMON_NAME.pid

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start () {
    log_daemon_msg "Starting system $DAEMON_NAME daemon"
    start-stop-daemon --start --background --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --user $DAEMON_USER --chuid $DAEMON_USER --startas $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
    log_end_msg $?
}
do_stop () {
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping system $DAEMON_NAME daemon"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PIDFILE --retry 10
    log_end_msg $?
}

case "$1" in
    start|stop)
        do_${1}
        ;;
    restart|reload|force-reload)
        do_stop
        do_start
        ;;
    status)
        status_of_proc "$DAEMON_NAME" "$DAEMON" && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$DAEMON_NAME {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: It's probably easy, but I think the question needs some details of the code to get a specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will edit the question to add some details.

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but you could check supervisord, it's a tool for managain demonized apps.